# How to choose $\epsilon$ for limit of a variable?

Tags: calculus, limits

> A constant number $a$ is said to be the limit of a variable $x$, if
>   for every preassigned arbitrarily small positive number $\epsilon$ it
>   is possible to indicate a value of the variable $x$ such that all
>   subsequent values of the variable will satisfy the inequality
>   $|x-a|<\epsilon$

Does this mean that $\epsilon$ will change according to the problem under consideration?

For example, if the problem needs a variable $x$ in the range of $[0,2]$, then $\epsilon$ can be $0.1$ or $0.01$

but if the problem needs a variable $x$ in the range of $[0,2000]$, then $\epsilon$ can be $1$ or $2$

I am confused by the word "preassigned", can I just replace "every preassigned" with "any" ?

Answer (score 2):

It's attempting to highlight the fact that the interval of values satisfying $|x-a|<\epsilon$ doesn't depend on the value of $\epsilon$. I think it's a bad way to put things. You can think of this as "for every $\epsilon$ there exists an interval around $a$ such that...

Symbolically, we understand this to mean 
$\forall\epsilon\exists\delta$, where $\delta$ depends on $\epsilon$ such that $|x-a|<\delta\Rightarrow |x-a|<\epsilon$. Here $\delta$ gives the radius of the interval, because it's center is $a$. We can tell that this is true by picking $\delta=\epsilon/2$. Now we have that $$\forall\epsilon, |x-a|<\epsilon/2\Rightarrow |x-a|<\epsilon$$ which can is a true statement.

One reason this might be confusing is that as $x$ goes to $a$ the limit of $x$ is just $x$. I think your paragraph is exceptionally unclear. In general, we say that $L$ is the limit of $f(x)$ as $x$ goes to $a$ if 
$\forall\epsilon\exists\delta$, such that $|x-a|<\delta\Rightarrow |f(x)-a|<\epsilon$.

Comment: but then for bigger $\epsilon$, $|x-a_1|$ and $|x-a_2|$ both will be less than chosen $\epsilon$, then which one is the limit?

Comment: @Vikram I'm not sure what you mean. I added some for info

Comment: I am also not getting my doubts cleared, suppose $x = 2$ and $a=1.99$, then $|x-a|= 0.01$ and let $\epsilon= 0.001$, then $|x-a| \nless \epsilon$, then $a$ is not the limit of $x$

Comment: You should be a bit careful: if you want to write it as a function then the existential should actually be on the outside, i.e. "there exists $f$ such that for every $\epsilon$, ..."

Comment: @Ian oh yes. Fuck it, I'm going to convert everything to deltas

Answer (score 0):

If $L$ is limit of $f$ at a point $a$.

$\epsilon$ should be arbitrary, but $\delta$ you can choose it to satisfies the definition.

So that ,for every   $\epsilon >0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that $0<|x-a|<\delta$ ,then $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$

Comment: I think "every" and "any" here have the same meaning .